# Filter [[NSDisctionary]] in swift

Tags: ios, swift, filtering, nsdictionary

I have an array of dictionaries I am trying to filter out the data as needed where the "displayName" is equal or matching with SearchText but result get all value of dictionary kindly let me know where I am wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh6la.png) 
data I am getting is like this in image

where dic is like    `static var singleDetails = [[NSDictionary]]()`
here is my code to filter

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
 {
  let results = variables.sinDetails.filter() { ($0[0]["displayName"] as? String) != searchText }

   }
```

Comment: Don't use things like a dictionary (especially an untyped dictionary) inside a double array. Swift is not Javascript. Use structs and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let results = variables.sinDetails.filter() { 
        ($0[0]["displayName"] as? String).contains(searchText) 
    }
}
```